# Grails - unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: grails, plugins

Installed a fresh copy of Grails 2.3.7 (needed for an older project)  on a machine and tried to create a sample application just to test but i'm unable to resolve a number of dependencies

```
>>>> org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.0.2
>>>> org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.1
>>>> org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.9
>>>> org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.3.8
>>>> org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0.2
>>>> org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.7
>>>> org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.52.1
```

Tried with a couple of other 2.x.x releases and got the same problem  ... I realise that the latest versions are 3.x.x but has the support for older versions been completely removed ??

My build.config looks like ..

```
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

Has something moved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Artifactory repo at repo.grails.org is down (you'll see it redirect to https://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/#/home and stop there with just a blank page) and it is being looked at, but there's been no ETA yet on when it will be back. This has happened a couple of times in the past and it can take several hours to be available again, but it shouldn't be more than a day total.

Comment: Update: it's now back online, so everything should be working as usual

Answer (score 0):

The maven.org repo has been reliable for me. Put it as the first, or even as the only, mavenRepo:

```
mavenRepo 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
```